# Take Any Numeric Primitive Array in Function

Tags: java, arrays, function, primitive

I want to write a function that will take any numeric 2D array. Using Java's object types, this is easy, as I can do something like:

```
public void process2DArray(Number [][] array) {
    // processing...
}
```

However, it'd be much easier to use if I could expand this function take any primitives, although, as arrays aren't autoboxed, the following code doesn't work:

```
double [][] array = new double [][] {{1,2},{3,4}};
process2DArray(array); // cannot invoke on array type double[][]
```

This function is going to process all numbers in the same way.

The best way I can think of to solve this to create a function for each primitive type which converts the array to a Number [][] type, and then passes it to the function. This just seems a little clunky - is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an elegant way to do it if you want to keep your code efficient. Your suggested solution of having multiple methods converting the primitive arrays to `Number[][]` is very inefficient - it involves boxing all the primitive values of your arrays.

That's why the JDK duplicates the same code for different primitive types.

You can see examples in `Arrays` static methods. For example, it contains 14 `sort` methods for 7 different primitive array types.

Answer (score 1):

> The best way I can think of to solve this to create a function for
>   each primitive type (or at least one for long and one for double)
>   which converts the array to a Number [][] type, and then passes it to
>   the function. This just seems a little clunky - is there a more
>   elegant way?

Overloading for each primitive type is not necessary bad.
It is efficient as it avoid boxing operations and numerical promoting.

The question is so : Which is you goal ? Having concise code that is less efficient or having longer code that is more efficient.